# What does jerry means here by the line,and to whom?

Tags: grammar, usage

It's a clip from a cartoon ***Rick&Morty***, with the link down below.

After Jerry (Morty's father) <strike>stroke</strike> struck the monster (don't exactly know what that's called) down  with a poker, he said this:

> Well, look where being smart got you.

What does it mean? to whom he said?

Could you please help me to understand more about lines like this one?

link:https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/b1a0802b-1bb4-46b7-b6d2-062d60fd9836

Comment: Being 'smart' (clever) didn't help the monster. Your link doesn't show enough of the cartoon for me to know in what way the monster had been smart and why it was a disadvantage. (BTW, he _struck_ the monster down - that's the past tense of _strike_.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Look where [something] got you*" is an idiomatic phrase, usually said disparagingly, and it serves to highlight the (bad) results or consequences of something you did.

In your example, the inference is that 'being smart' resulted in something bad. Perhaps it was said in response to a suggestion that they had done something 'stupid', to point out that their way was no better.

Comment: it could just be something you say when you are clubbing something to death, like 'put that that in your pipe and smoke it' or 'here's something to think about', etc.